# Prove that $O(3)\cong SO(3)\times\{I, -I\} \cong SO(3)\times C_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that $O(3)\cong SO(3)\times\{I, -I\} \cong SO(3)\times C_2$.
>   Conclude that every finite subgroup of $O(3)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $H\times K$, where $H$ is a finite subgroup of $SO(3)$ and $|K| = 1$ or $2$.

My book didn't define what $O(3)$ was. But looking it up I see that it says $O(3) = SO(3) × \{ I , −I \}$. Which would mean that I'm just proving that it is isomorphic to itself.
Secondly. My book did not define what $C_2$ is. I tried looking up a conceptual definition but I can not find anything.

I would appreciate any help in proceeding with this problem. I have an idea of how to show they are isomorphic to one another but I can't figure out the terminology here.

Comment: $O(3)$ is the [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group), the group consisting of all $3 \times 3$ (real) orthogonal matrices.  $SO(3)$ is the *special orthogonal group*, namely $SO(3) = \{A \in O(3) \mid \det(A) = 1\}$.

Comment: Dear @Nid, instead of x write $\times$ which is given by \times.

Answer (score 2):

Like Alvin said, $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order 2.  Omnomnomnom said that the orthogonal group $O(3)$ is the group of all 3$\times$3 real orthogonal matrices; I should add that an "orthogonal matrix" is a matrix $Q$ such that $Q^T = Q^{-1}$, which will necessarily have determinant 1 or -1.  So

$$
O(3) = \{A \in M_{3 \times 3} \mid Q^T = Q^{-1}\}
$$
and
$$
SO(3) = \{A \in O(3) \mid \det(A) = 1\}
$$
Now, prove that the map $\varphi: O(3) \rightarrow SO(3) \times \{1, -1\}$ given by
$$
\varphi(A) = \left(\det(A) \cdot A, \det(A) \right)
$$
is an isomorphism.
To do this, you need to show that the codomain of $\varphi$ is indeed $SO(3) \times \{1, -1\},$ that it is a homomorphism, and that it is a bijection.  (For these, you need to use properties of the determinant, namely that it is multiplicative.)

Once this is done, you need to show that a subgroup $G$ of $SO(3) \times C_2$ must be $H \times K$ for some subgroups $H \subseteq SO(3)$ and $K \subseteq C_2$.  If you were a super good student, you might also explain why, if $G$ is a subgroup of $O(3)$, then it must be isomorphic to a subgroup of $SO(3) \times C_2$.  (This part is not meant to be the meat of the problem, but can be a good exercise.)

Comment: I think $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism because $I\in SO(3)$ has two inverse images: $I,-I$.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten to write the second component of the tuple.

Comment: and the definitions of $O(3)$ and $SO(3)$ are incorrect. The matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$$ has determinant 1 but it is not in $SO(3)$

Comment: I think that in the first sentence of your last paragraph, you mean "show that a subgroup $G$ of $SO(3)\times C_2$ must be *a subgroup* of $H\times K$ for ....."  other wise it's not true.  For example, consider $G = \langle \operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1), -1\rangle\cong C_2$ is not of the form $H\times K$.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be "Every finite subgroup of $O(3)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $H \times K$ of $SO(3) \times C_2$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $SO(3)$ and $|K| = 1$ or $2$."

Answer (score 0):

$C_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$.

Consider $g: SO(3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ given by $g(A,\bar{0}) = A$ and $g(A,\bar{1}) = -A$.  Note that $\det(-A) = - \det(A) = - 1$ so $-A \in O(3) \setminus SO(3)$ so $g$ is a continuous bijection. $SO(3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is compact and $O(3)$ is Hausdorff so this is a homeomorphism.

More generally, $SO(n) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is homeomorphic but not isomorphic to $O(n)$ if $n$ is even (look at the center of $O(n)$, which consists of $I_n$ and $-I_n$).  They are both homeomorphic and isomorphic when $n$ is odd.  For example, consider the matrix $M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & \ddots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$
with $1$ on the diagonal for all except the last entry and zeros everywhere else.
Consider $f: SO(n) \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \to O(n)$ defined by $f(A,\bar{0}) = A$ and $f(A,\bar{1}) = M \cdot A$.

Comment: It suffices to take $M = -I$, which is more convenient

Comment: I apologize but I'm taking Abstract Algebra for the firs time. We have yet to learn what homeomorphisms are or Hausdorff.